# Is there a canonical book on Scala?

Tags: books, scala

I'm interested in learning Scala, but due to is relative newness, I can't seem to find a whole lot of books about it.

Is there a book out there that's the de-facto standard for describing best practices, design methodologies, and other helpful information on Scala? What makes that book special?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/194812/203968 list a few free ones

Comment: this may help: http://www.scalacommunity.com/post_top_5_scala_programming_books_money_can_buy_1367336392401

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I can advise [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala) because it's from  the creator of the Scala language: Martin Odersky.

He describes most of the features of Scala very detailedly and explains, why he chose this feature instead of an other one. Therefore, the reader gets a deep insight into Scala. The book is fantastic. It is one of the best programming books I've ever read.

Comment: Lex Spoon, one of the co-authors, is a clear communicator and Clever Dude (see his Squeak Smalltalk contributions); that bodes well for the book!

Comment: I've been told by both the head of our department and a PhD candidate that I'm good friends with that this is currently the best book on the language.  Both of them are fans of Scala, and have large enough libraries that I trust their insight into which books are worth it and which aren't (as they tell me about those that aren't worth it quite often).

Comment: @Frank: Great. I didn't know Spoon was also a Smalltalk guy. :)

Comment: Small side note, Programming in Scala second edition was just released. It includes updates and changes in scala 2.8.

Comment: Programming in Scala,Third edition is now out, conforms to Scala 2.11/12

Answer (score 8):

Artima's [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala) is the best Scala book you can get at the moment. **Very recommended.** I found O'Reilly's [Programming Scala](http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/) to be a good second book; It moves a bit faster than I'd like though.

I also tried David Pollak's [Beginning Scala](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430219897) but didn't quite like it, and I **don't** recommend it to anyone.

All the above-mentioned books are somewhat oudated as they don't cover a lot of things new in Scala 2.8. I am hoping that the updated editions of these books will be published soon.

---

Though more than half a dozen Scala books have already been published, I believe that the best books are yet to come.

The two books in particular that I think you should keep your eye on are:

1. [Scala in Depth](http://www.manning.com/suereth/) by Josh Suereth
2. [Steps in Scala](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521747589) by Christos Loverdos and Apostolos Syropoulos

Comment: I would O'Reilly's Programming Scala is the best book for those who want to kick start and get their feet wet on scala and Artima's Programming in Scala is a great book for reference much like the Java - The complete reference book

Comment: @prassee: Agree with the first part; disagree with the second.